# An array of UIImageViews in objective-c

Tags: java, objective-c, arrays, uiimageview

I already had many UIImageViews.. I want to make an array of UIImageViews and assign every element of the array with one of the UIImageViews above.. How can I do that with objective c??
I did it in java like the following:

```
JLabel l1=new JLabel();
JLabel l2=new JLabel();
JLabel [] arrayOfLabels = new JLabel[2];
arrayOfLabel[0] = l1;
arrayOfLabel[1] = l2;
```

I need to do the same thing in objective c..

Comment: Where do you have your many image views? How are they defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer you according to your Java Statements for better clarity:

```
   //Java:
    JLabel l1=new JLabel();

    //Objective C:
    UIImageView * l1= [[UIImageView alloc] init];


    //Java:
    JLabel l2=new JLabel();

    //Objective C:
    UIImageView * l2 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];


    //Java 
    JLabel [] arrayOfLabels = new JLabel[2]; 

    //Objective C 
    NSMutableArray * imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Java 
    arrayOfLabel[0] = l1;

    //Objective C 
    [imagesArray addObject:l1];


    //Java
    arrayOfLabel[1] = l2; 

    //Objective C
    [imagesArray addObject:l2];
```

Since you are not using ARC (i guessed it from your comment), so therefore you must release the things manually as part of memory management as:

```
     [l1 release];  //After adding it to imagesArray

     [l2 release];  //After adding it to imagesArray
```

And release the `imagesArray` when you don't need it. Normally it is done in `dealloc()`, but you can release it at any point where you don't need it further by simply calling:

```
    [imagesArray release];
    imagesArray = nil;
```

Hope so this will help you.

Comment: `imagesArray[0] = l1` is legal too, more java-esque.

Comment: Just use ARC @nouf, unless of course there is a really good reason you can't... In that case `[imagesArray release]` when you no longer need it. and `[l1 release]` and `[l2 release]` after you add them to the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
UILabel * l1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
UILabel * l2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * arrayOfLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
arrayOfLabels[0] = l1;
arrayOfLabels[1] = l2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *view1;
UIImageView *view2;
// assuming they are already instantiated
NSMutableArray *arrayOfImageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrayOfImageViews addObject:view1];
[arrayOfImageViews addObject:view2];
```

Comment: So view1 is at index 0 and view2 at index 1 right??.. what if then i wanted to change the element at index 1 to view1 ?? i mean how can i access a specific element for modifying??

Comment: That would be `[arrayOfImageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:1 with Object:view1];`. Note that the array contains **pointers** to real objects (e.g. view1, view2). You can't modify a pointer, only replace. However you can modify the element the pointer points to. You can access it with `[arrayOfImageViews objectAtIndex:1]`

Answer (score 0):

Using the more modern syntax you can say

```
NSArray *myViewArray=@[ view1, view2, view3 ];
```